# How to make query to show additional field when field with name information similar in two rows?

Tags: ms-access

I need to make query when two fields similar show additional city field. How to make hide and show field when duplicate values in fields?

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result. If you want to concatenate data from multiple records, that is a common topic.

Comment: For example i have 3 fields - name, surname, city When i query for some name and i got 2 rows then i show also ciry field but if 1 row i dont show city field. How to make it ? Its sound simple but i have too small expierence

Comment: Why is this necessary? Why not just show City regardless?

Comment: For example when i input name John and i got 3 Johns i need also city field to see 3 Johns from dfferent cities but if 1 John i dont need city field

Comment: Could do an expression in query like: `Cty: IIf(DCount("*", "Table", "[Name] & [Surname] = '" & [Name] & [Surname] & "'")<2, "", [City])` Still don't think this is worth bother.

Answer (score 0):

for example, you have a Textbox (Textbox1) to search for the (Name)
and another Textbox (Textbox2) for the (Surname) 
also you have a Database (MyDatabase)
Containing table named (MyTable), with fields (PersonName, PersonSurName, PersonCity)
Also, Datagridview (DataGridView1)
Finally, A button (Button1)
Under Button1.Click event, use this code:

```
 Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MyDatabase.accdb")
        cnn.Open()

        Try
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE PersonName = @myname and PersonSurName = @mysurname"
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myname", TextBox1.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mysurname", TextBox2.Text)
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                If dt.Rows.Count <= 1 Then
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    Dim column3 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(2)
                    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
                Else
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("error : " + ex.Message)
        End Try

        cnn.Close()
    End Using
```

and you should get what you want...